# Binding de um checkbox com a ViewModel sem o uso do Razor (Asp.net core MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5, asp.net, asp.net-core, checkbox

Estou tendo problemas com o Razor... Preciso criar um campo checkbox e fazer o binding com minha viewModel usando html puro. Só que não estou conseguindo fazer o binding corretamente com a propriedade do tipo bool e mesmo que eu seleciono ou não o checkbox, quando faço submit, fica sempre false o valor... Como faço o binding corretamente? (os campos estão sendo criados dinamicamente...)

```
<div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
    <input type="checkbox" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" autocomplete="off" />
    <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
</div>
```

Consegui resolver o problema validando a propriedade checked, mas está correto?

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@i].ContatoPrincipal" value="true" checked ="@(Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal)" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" autocomplete="off" />
        <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, tenta definir um valor padrão pra ele, `value="true" checked`, assm, havendo alguma mudança ele vai identificar e enviar pro controller. Faça o teste e me avise.

Comment: Olá @VictorLaio! Eu adicionei value="true" e resolveu a parte do submit. O checked está atrapalhando, pois quando ele retorna o modelo para a view, ela fica sempre true, independente se a propriedade bool esteja true ou false. O que fazer srsr

Comment: @VictorLaio, eu atualizei meu post com uma possível solução no qual deu certo, mas não sei se seria a forma correta. Eu setei value="true" e usei o razor para validar o checked, pois ao receber o registro do banco, ele seta certinho... O que vc acha?

Comment: Acho viável, apesar de que você não queria usar o Razor mas acabou funcionando! Enjoy! Hehe. Vou postar a resposta então.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve colocar uma propriedade pra ele de checked ou não, pois ele identifica as alterações como se fosse um evento "on".

Adiciona esta parte no seu checkbox:

```js
value="true" checked
```

Como você mencionou, pode tentar usar o razor para definir se ele realmente está checked ou não deixando da seguinte maneira:

```js
checked ="@(Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal)"
```

Qualquer dúvida e se eu puder ajudar de mais alguma maneira é só me avisar! :)

Comment: Obrigado @Victor Laio! Sua ajuda foi muito importante. Abraço! :)